# How to deserialize JSON field with dynamic type?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, json-deserialization

In a request to the Reddit API, there is a field associated with each post called `edited`.  This field either has a `boolean` value or if a post has been edited, has a `long` value which I think is the timestamp of when the post was edited.  How can I deserialize this with GSON *without* knowing the type?  If I try to deserialize into a `Boolean` value I get an exception if a timestamp is present.

Image below of JSON response:

[image: JSON response]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotating the dynamic field with `@JsonAdapter` is probably the easiest way to work around this (assuming you have a DTO class):

```java
final class Datum {

    @JsonAdapter(MaybeLongTypeAdapter.class)
    final Long edited = null;

}
```

Where `MaybeLongTypeAdapter` is as follows:

```java
final class MaybeLongTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Long> {

    private MaybeLongTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Long value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Long read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        switch ( in.peek() ) {
        case NULL:
            return null;
        case BOOLEAN:
            if ( in.nextBoolean() ) {
                throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unexpected `true` at " + in);
            }
            return null;
        case NUMBER:
            return in.nextLong();
        default:
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Unexpected element at " + in);
        }
    }

}
```

The type adapter above is pretty self-descriptive. It can be implemented in a more generic way, of course, but it's out of scope here. Additionally, please note that it does not pick the original `Long` type adapter that can be re-configured in `GsonBuilder`. Example of use:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

private static final Type listOfDatumType = new TypeToken<List<Datum>>() {}.getType();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final String json = "[{\"edited\": false},{\"edited\": 1527130582}]";
    final List<Datum> data = gson.fromJson(json, listOfDatumType);
    for ( final Datum datum : data ) {
        System.out.println(datum.edited);
    }
}
```

Output:

> null
>   1527130582